# How to access type traits from a given (deferred) pointer type?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class template like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    typedef T inferred_type;
};
```

And somewhere else I see a deferred type of

```
typedef MyClass<int>* param_type;
```

But `MyClass<int>*` is deferred and I don't know that `int` is used for instantiation here. I'm actually accessing another typedef for `MyClass<int>*`.

Can I somehow get to `MyClass<int>::inferred_type` from that pointer typedef?

**EDIT**:

Regarding [RiaD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768110/riad)'s answer, the following line does what I need:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<param_type>::value_type::inferred_type TheDecucedInferredType;
```

Note that `typename` is only needed since `param_type` itself is a template parameter, within the context I see there.

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code that's going to be using this?

Comment: @greatwolf Bit tricky! It's [tag:googlemock] actually that does the deferring with a typedef like this. I can't see `MyClass<int>` type directly, since it's already passed in as a pointer type (it's kinda `auto` mechanism, can't tell the details and tricks they've used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `iterator_traits`

```
typename std::iterator_traits<Pointer>::value_type //if Pointer is MyClass<int>*, then it will be MyClass<int>
```

After that you may wrote `value_type` once more to get `int`.

It will work with pointers and standard iterators.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean this `value_type` actually. Was just a sample, the real code uses a different typedef name.

Comment: Em... I've clarified a bit. Maybe I didn't get the question through.

Comment: _'Maybe I didn't get the question through'_ In real code it's not `MyClass::value_type` but `MyClass::something_else`. Doubt this would work with `std::iterator_traits<T>`, right?

Comment: then you can use `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type::something_else`

Comment: Ahh! Now I can see your point! That looks viable, but has confusing semantic hints (regarding the `std::iterator' reference a.s.o). But I'd guess it would also work similarly as the other answers stated, right? Would a typedef fit here as well (to clarifiy semantics)?

Comment: Hmmmmm, looking closer: Where would i get `T` for `std::iterator_traits<T>` from?? `MyClass` is already a template class, which template parameters are not known at get the point I want to get `value_type`.

Comment: This solution has only 1 advantage: you needn't write any code. Basically `iterator_traits` is as `remove_pointer` in solution of celtschk, but also specified for iterators, not only pointers. I didn't get the question about typedef. You may typedef it as long as you know T

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33460/discussion-between-riad-and-g-makulik)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "type function":

```
template<typename T> struct remove_pointer { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct remove_pointer<T*> { typedef T type; };
```

Then if `ptrtype` is your pointer typedef (or template argument, or whatever), you can write

```
MyClass<remove_pointer<ptrtype>::type>::value_type
```

C++11 conveniently has such a template `remove_pointer` predefined.

Comment: Aaah! Interesting technique! Wouldn't have ever thought about this direction. I'll try that and come back.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 and only if `MyClass` definition is visible you can do

```
typedef MyClass<int>* type;

std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<type>())>::type::value_type
```

Without C++11 you can do

```
template<typename T>
struct get_value_type;

template<typename T>
struct get_value_type<T*>
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};

typedef MyClass<int>* type;
get_value_type<type>::value_type
```

Comment: I explicitly didn't tag [tag:c++11], I know that. THX for an answer though.

Comment: @g-makulik I'll add a c++ version

Comment: Yes, that's in principle the same thing @celtschk provided in his answer, right?

Comment: @g-makulik Yep! In general boost type traits will help achieving many similar situations